# VPN through NetworkManager in Debian?

Tags: vpn, debian, networkmanager, vpnc

I just switched over to Debian from Ubuntu and I can't seem to figure out how to add a VPN connection through network manager.  When I select the VPN tab from Edit Connections the Add button is disabled.

I'm running a fresh install of Debian 6.0.1 Already install the the Cisco VPN client (network-manager-vpnc).

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not seeing the VPN manager you have installed. Once you install one that's supported, like openvpn, the Add button will be enabled.

Comment: Hmm, I've added openvpn and network-manager-openvpn but no joy.  Even after restarting NetworkManager the Add button is disabled.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried this?It looked like it from your question but I wasn't certain    #sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc vpnc

Comment: Yep, vpnc and network-manager-vpnc are already installed.

Comment: Might seem unrelated but are you using gnome?

Comment: If you are you might need to do it like #apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome AND #apt-get install network-manager-vpnc-gnome

Answer (score 4):

You have to install the network manager:

```
sudo aptitude install network-manager-vpnc
```

As well as the gnome client:

```
sudo aptitude install network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

Answer (score 0):

On @Sileria answer, Also you have to install the network manager and gnome client for PPTP connection type:

```
sudo aptitude install network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome
```